# Is a shortcut to front-end database wise?

Tags: ms-access

On our network I have set up a folder "admindb" containing a number of databses, front end and backend. I have given various staff members shortcuts to the front ends. This is easier for me than giving them the actual front end as if I make changes to design I don't have to keep distributing new front ends. However When users have logged out of a database, the "record-locking" file remains open in admindb. To resolve this I have to open and close the database in admindb. I this a good method or should I always distribute actual front ends and not shortcuts?

Answer (score 4):

The front-end can get corrupted easily if shared. To help prevent this, I normally create a file that will copy the latest front-end to the workstation, if it is newer than the one on the workstations, and launch it. The shortcut is pointing to the shared .bat file.  As long as the backend is set to shared and not set to single user, this file should never locked.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely *must* copy the front-end file to the local hard drive of *each user*. If you have more than one user sharing the same copy of the front-end file then you are very likely to encounter strange errors and poor performance.

Answer (score 1):

*"When users have logged out of a database, the "record-locking" file remains open in admindb"*

Normally as Access exits, it checks the lock file (`.ldb` or `.laccdb`) to see whether the db is still in use by any other process.  And when the current Access session was the last user, it will delete the lock file.  When the user account lacks delete permission for the admindb folder, Access can't remove the lock file.

However the stale/unused lock file should not be a problem.  When it's present, the next database connection will use it and update as needed.

Seems to me the bigger problem is sharing the same copy of the front end db file among multiple users.  If you can't give each user their own file as the other answers recommend, at least consider changing the shortcuts so the front end databases are opened in exclusive mode.  That way the front end files would still be shared in a sense, but never at the same time.